# Can someone please explain the <Func<T, bool>> in a simple way for me

Tags: c#

I am looking at code containing:

```
public virtual ICollection<T> GetPk(string pk)
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = c => c.PartitionKey == pk;
    return this.GetAll(predicate);
}
```

Can someone explain the syntax of `<Func<T, bool>>` ?

Answer (score 5):

Simply `Func<T, bool>` is the anonymous method signature. The first type `T` is the input parameter type and the second type is the return type. This is more like a method when you consider your representation:

```
bool AnonMethod(T arg0)
{
   return arg0.PartitionKey == pk;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the best explanation can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)

> You can use this delegate to represent a method that can be passed as a parameter without explicitly declaring a custom delegate. The encapsulated method must correspond to the method signature that is defined by this delegate. This means that the encapsulated method must have one parameter that is passed to it by value, and that it must return a value.

As for argument in your example T is the type of input parameter and bool is the return type of exacted method.

Answer (score 4):

A `Func<T, bool>` represents a function that takes an object of type `T` and returns a `bool`. It's commonly referred to as a "predicate", and is used to verify a condition on an object.

An `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` represents the [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of the function, i.e. its syntactic structure. It can be used to analyse the code of the function for various purposes, such as transforming it to SQL to be executed against a database.

Answer (score 2):

For some background; prior to `Func<T, TResult>` (and the rest of this family) being part of the framework, you either had to explicitly define delegates or use anonymous methods.

`Func` and `Action` were added as part of the addition of lambda expressions to the language. They are the framework-defined delegates which lambda expressions are typed as, but which you as a developer can also use in place of your own custom delegate definitions.

You can get a nice history here;

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/10/03/lambda-expressions.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I always find MSDN to be worth checking on things like this first,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx

Beaten by Maheep, didn't see the post message pop-in.

Basically, you're declaring a method that matches a signature, that can then be passed in to the call to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

It is confusing at first but `Func<T, bool>` describes a function that returns a bool and accepts a parameter as type T.

In this case, T is an object that has a `PartitionKey` property and this `GetPk` method is using the `Func<T, bool>` to match all the T items in the instance object which have a `PartitionKey` that matches the string `pk`.

Answer (score 0):

It's additional [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) so you know what goes in and out of the function.

`Func<T, bool>` means: 
function has **1 input** `T` and **1 output** that's `bool`.

[This is other variations of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPQMv.png)